# longest match in python

Tags: python, string

I am new in python.I have data in a 2d- array in the following format.

```
array[0]                                              array[1]
Arkan                                                 Adrian Edmondson
Efgan All                                             Rik 
'Til Death Do Us Part (Star Trek: Deep Space Nine)    Bradley Thompson
'Til Death Do Us Part (Star Trek: Deep Space Nine)    David Weddle
Billy Sherrill                                       'Til I Can Make It on My Own (Deep Space)
```

I want to match this string for each line in a file, if matches both array then I want to  return the line.
First, I want search the both array in each line .For that my attempt was:

```
def strinMach(domainL, rangeR):
    text = ""
    filetext = open(File, "r").read()
        sentlist = re.split(u'[\n|\r\n]+',filetext)
    for i in sentlist:
        if domainL in i and rangeR in i:                
            text = text + i + "\n"
        elif (To search for without the parenthesis string from array[0] & array[1]
              eg.search with (Til Death Do Us Part        Bradley Thompson ) )
        elif (To search with some string from array[0] & array[1]
               es. search with(Till Death   Bradley) or (Do Us Part  Thompson))
    return text
```

My second step is seraching with the array except the parenthesis string (i.e except (terms)
).

And third step with the substring of both array.

How to proceed on for 2nd & 3rd step.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: *cough* `for line in open(thefile, "r")` should save you some typing.

Comment: You should be more descriptive about what exactly is not working here.

Comment: Actually, it works! but I also want to search without the parenthesis string & substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a bit of trouble working out what you're asking, but maybe this will help:

You can remove a bracketed section of a string with:

```
thetext = re.sub(r"\(.*?\)", "", thetext)
```

(N.B. This won't work properly if you have "((nested) brackets)")

You can get substrings by slicing:

```
thetext[4:10]
thetext[:5]   # First 5 characters
thetext[-5:]  # Last 5 characters
thetext[:-1]  # All but the last character
```